# Parsing the wbxml get from Exchange2013 server

Tags: exchange-server, wbxml

Below is a full section of bytes stream I got from Exchange2013 server after sending activesync command 'itemoperations' from iPhone.

31 139 8 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 237 189 7 96 28 73 150 37 38 47 109 202 123 127 74 245 74 215 224 116 161 8 128 96 19 36 216 144 64 16 236 193 136 205 230 146 236 29 105 71 35 41 171 42 129 202 101 86 101 93 102 22 64 204 237 157 188 247 222 123 239 189 247 222 123 239 189 247 186 59 157 78 39 247 223 255 63 92 102 100 1 108 246 206 74 218 201 158 33 128 170 200 31 63 126 124 31 63 34 126 237 95 243 167 127 141 95 227 183 58 253 226 215 222 253 53 126 205 23 207 248 199 175 241 155 255 196 175 125 255 119 191 151 61 220 167 127 240 247 111 245 123 253 26 191 249 119 127 237 54 127 215 222 93 149 89 177 196 71 207 127 237 215 95 61 124 253 229 79 31 191 251 226 233 233 15 126 234 167 143 175 190 248 233 183 87 95 60 61 198 255 119 190 124 243 19 59 47 62 255 226 7 191 207 155 159 250 233 23 139 223 231 222 139 167 211 221 23 63 248 226 250 167 126 250 247 217 161 191 247 126 234 233 239 115 255 197 226 171 189 159 250 233 239 44 94 252 244 23 244 115 122 253 226 167 207 246 190 120 67 127 63 125 187 67 237 174 95 44 78 247 94 188 249 125 126 240 226 7 63 177 75 144 232 253 179 123 47 126 154 127 18 220 47 222 125 177 248 234 7 218 159 254 255 212 251 221 252 127 26 126 255 6 248 30 95 253 212 27 243 25 193 249 193 219 31 124 241 211 223 41 191 248 193 233 15 8 151 125 134 251 70 254 254 242 233 23 215 95 60 125 50 255 125 246 126 159 61 250 219 194 122 241 148 218 253 128 218 253 244 23 192 237 7 47 8 159 23 63 125 122 77 227 218 37 24 10 231 39 8 206 23 87 244 61 189 251 157 183 47 126 250 43 140 135 218 31 83 59 124 126 76 99 195 223 103 123 47 208 15 141 235 139 31 224 221 51 130 71 125 124 206 116 217 121 241 131 175 238 125 241 131 87 229 139 207 127 31 162 171 224 255 133 197 95 255 14 199 255 238 133 163 129 155 31 249 158 254 254 170 67 163 83 31 30 254 255 217 175 241 107 226 249 127 0 225 220 243 27 28 2 0 0

I don't know why it is not normal and expect it sholud start like this:
 3 1 106 0 0 20 69 77 3 49 0 1 78 70 77 3 49 0 1 0 17 81 3 82 103 65 65 65 65 65 117 50 72 120 85 112 65 ..........

I think the response must have been encrypted, but what's the encryption algorithm?

Will be very appreciated for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer, the stream 31 139 8 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 237 189 7 96 28 73 150 37 ...... has been compressed by Gzip

Comment: can you tell me how to make request to get data from Exchange2013 server. i just want to know the process.Thanks. @Terry